# How change the layout (e.g. background-color) of autoplaylists in foobar2000?

Tags: media-player, foobar2000

A nice feature of the highly customizable music player foobar2000 is to generate autoplaylists. Autoplaylists are filtered lists of music that automatically update when you add new music to your collection.

You would usually generate one by searching for something and saving it as new autoplaylists, e.g.:

> %added% DURING LAST 4 WEEKS
>
> %genre% HAS jazz OR %genre% HAS downtempo
>
> %date% GREATER 1949 AND %date% LESS 1970

Autoplaylist playlists are locked: You can't add or delete files. You can note that thanks to the little icon in the status bar at the bottom of your screen: [image: autoplaylist icon]

foobar2000 let's you customize nearly everything, so here is my question:

Is there a way to change the layout of the autoplaylists?

For example i want to change the background-color in my playlist view.
I use the Columns UI component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns_UI let's you [change background colors](http://yuo.be/wiki/columns_ui:config:colour_string#setting_the_background_colour)

[image]

But it's ugly like hell.